# Sort by keyword index mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering if there was a way to sort my mongodb results by the index of the search keyword.

For example if I search the db by `{name: da}` i'll get back results like `[{name: "yoda"}, {name: "david"}, {name: "soda"}, {name: "daniel"}]`. But I would want the order to be something like this `[{name: "david"}, {name: "daniel"}, {name: "yoda"}, {name: "soda"}]`. I know that I can sort the results after I find them like this:

> `const re = new RegExp(keyword, "i");`
> `results.sort((a, b) => a.name.search(re) - b.name.search(re)`

But I also wanted to limit the amount of documents I get back from the database. I looked at the textScore metadata in the mongodb docs, but I have no clue if its useful in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the criteria to limit documents returned? you can use aggregation below to get matched results sorted based on the index of match. please note we did exact match if you need case insensitive match then you need to use $toUpper while getting index.

```
[{$match: {
  name: {$regex:/da/}
}}, {$addFields: {
  matchedIndex: { $indexOfCP: [ "$name", "da" ] }
}}, {$sort: {
  matchedIndex: 1
}}, {$project: {
  matchedIndex: 0
}}]
```

Documentation reference:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/